# Cross Domain GeoLocation Tracking

Tags: javascript, geolocation, cross-domain

I am trying to track user location (HTML5 GeoLocation) on multiple domains, by asking user permission for once. For example:

- User gives permissions on `example.com`
- `example2.com` adds a script/iframe from `example.com`
- User enters on `example2.com`
- User location is tracked by `example.com` and location specific content is shown to user.

Currently, if I add an iframe from `example.com`, even `example.com` has permissions to track user location, browser is asking for location tracking again, since there's no permission on `example2.com`. Is there any way to remove multiple times permission asking process, since we will be inserting these location tracking widgets to multiple webpages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS the iframe would be able to send the GEOLocation information to the example.com page I would say and also hope that the user has to be asked again. Otherwise you would be able to track a users position from different pages using a hidden iframe and the user will never know about it, as he might have given that side a permission once.

Comment: Agreed. If you find any browsers that don't request your permission when an iframe is embedded in another site, please let me know so that we can file bugs against them.